# SQL Statement intermediate issue

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table where lots of products are stored.
Each row has 3 columns: ProductID, RevisionID, and Name

I need to make a sql statement to get a list of all the products, but only one for each ProductID.

However many rows can have the same ProductID but incrementing RevisionIDs.

So when getting all the products I need to make sure to only get one of each ProductID, and make sure them rows are the latest RevisionIDs.

SELECT * FROM #TABLE
WHERE ProductID is unique
AND this products RevisionID is the highest for all the ProductID rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
select t.*
from #table t join
     (select productid, max(revisionid) as maxri
      from #table
      group by productid
     ) tt
     on tt.productid = t.productid and tt.maxri = t.revisionid;
```